# How to reproduce this kind of bright effect animate on Blender?

Tags: particles, physics, smoke-simulation, volumetrics, effects

I need help to reproduce this kind of bright effect on Blender, but I want to animate it as well, the animation could be it just turning around in circle.

What do I need to search about to recreate this kind of effect ?
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Depends a little bit on how you want to create it. The "normal" way I'd say is, if you create an animation of emissive particle objects, then in the compositor you can add a _Glare_ node, maybe even combine multiple ones with different settings and mixing them together. The question is, how experienced are you with the compositor, how much advice do you need?

Comment: The compositor is really unknown to me.

Comment: you'll probably find some ideas here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/199172/create-a-trail-effect-meteor you can do it with a mix of material, particles, and compositing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a comet object that will be made of a ball (the head), a thin tail and a bigger one. Also create a curve, and give your comet object a *Curve* modifier to make it follow the curve. Create 3 different particles that will be your sparks:

[image]

Give your comet and particles this kind of node setup: *Emission* mixed with *Transparent* with a *Layer Weight* as factor, with a gradient on X for the tails, some noise to create texture, push a bit the *Emission* strength so that it can bloom:

[image]

Give your object a *Particle System > Emitter* in order to create the sparks. In the *Compositor* give your image a *Blur* and a *Glare* node to create the image effects:

[image]

Comment: I've follow your steps, but mine doesn't look quite like yours.
How can I show a result in here ?

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=zBGQMb43" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/zBGQMb43/)

Comment: please share your file (copy and paste here the url it will give you once you've uploaded the file): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Here is https://blend-exchange.com/b/zBGQMb43/

Comment: it seems to work, you need to give another material to your particles and to your comet itselft, don't give it noise, just pure Emission to begin, then you can try to mix with Transparent with Layer Weight as factor...

Comment: if you test the material in Eevee don't forget to go into the Material > Settings > Blend Mode > Alpha Blend in order to have transparency

Comment: This is my result, following the steps above 
https://pasteall.org/pic/e04582bce5304fab9361bac226e6b0ed

Comment: so you're not too far, you need to give a rather white color to both the comet itself and to the particles, push up the Emission strength, enable the Bloom option in the Render panel, in the Compositor give your image Blur and Glare

Comment: I did what you said, but I'm still getting issues in my render. The result that you got, is exactly what I need, but when I try to reproduce your steps, my result doesn't look even close yours. Could you check my file please? And let me know what is not correct ? That I need to change? I've created a material just to the "ball", another to the tail, another to the dusty, other to particles. I've added blur and glare on composite too, and messed around a lot with this, but nothing close. Can you check it please ?https://blend-exchange.com/b/w5D5Jnr3

Comment: use a lighter (whiter) color for the ball and the thin tail (i.e. lower the saturation value). For the Compositor, click on Backdrop and create an Output > Viewer, an dplug the Glare into the Viewer. V and Alt V to scale the backdrop