# cant export gltf properly

Tags: rendering, gltf, blend4web, webgl

iam trying to export my model in gltf format.
this is what i get when i try to view the exported file:
[image]

and this is what i want to have:

[image]

red circle is indicating yellow wire, it messes up completely for some reason.

here is [link to my project](https://www.mediafire.com/file/zl6lu8nmmolk0zn/blendo.zip/file). i included blend and gltf. if you can figure it out let me know
website i am testing on is https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com (specially picked it because it uses threejs)

Comment: This is similar to: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/220433/18161.  Essentially, all the glowing stuff requires "bloom" to be turned on.  You can turn on bloom in a ThreeJS app, but it is not stored in a glTF file nor enabled by default in Don's viewer.

Comment: doesn't really help tho

Comment: I would try converting non-mesh objects to meshes and applying transforms and modifiers before export. If that doesn't work you may need to file a bug on the exporter: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO